# How can I download file in my folder c# ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need a download file in my `C:\fileName`.

I am send to fileName this class but it does not working ?  Where is my error?

This is my code:

```
// POST: api/Calendar/DownloadFile
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(DownloadInput fileName)
{
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"C:\" + fileName);
        var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        var fileMemStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(fileMemStream);
        var headers = result.Content.Headers;
        headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
        headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        headers.ContentLength = fileMemStream.Length;

        return result;
}
```

This is my error:

> ExceptionType: "System.NotImplementedException"
>   Message: "An error has occurred."

Answer (score -1):

The below is for MVC:

```
  public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileWithFullPath)
    {                
        var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileWithFullPath);    
        return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

The below is for API:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var stream = new FileStream(fullyQualifiedFileName, FileMode.Open);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;

            string input = $"filename=test.pdf";
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
            if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(input, out contentDisposition))
            {
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
            }

            return this.ResponseMessage(result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you are showing here, the parameter DosyaAdi is a string and it is not clear what DownloadInput is.  I would suggest changing the input parameter to a string and also changing the Method to HttpGet.  The second suggestion is for convention and probably not the issue.

```
// GET: api/Calendar/DownloadFile
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(string DosyaAdi)...
```

good luck